# HtmlAgilityPack - SelectNodes

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to retrieve a `<p class>` element.

```
<div class="thread-plate__details">
    <h3 class="thread-plate__title">(S) HexHunter BOW</h3>
    <p class="thread-plate__summary">created by Aazoth</p>  <!-- (THIS ONE) -->
</div>
```

But with no luck.

The code I am using is below:

```
' the example url to scrape
            Dim url As String = "http://services.runescape.com/m=forum/forums.ws?39,40,goto," & Label6.Text
            Dim source As String = GetSource(url)

            If source IsNot Nothing Then
                ' create a new html document and load the pages source
                Dim htmlDocument As New HtmlDocument
                htmlDocument.LoadHtml(source)

                ' Create a new collection of all href tags
                Dim nodes As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class]")

                ' Using LINQ get all href values that start with http://
                ' of course there are others such as www.
                Dim links =
                    (
                        From node
                        In nodes
                        Let attribute = node.Attributes("class")
                        Where attribute.Value.StartsWith("created by ")
                        Select attribute.Value
                    )

                Me.ListBox1a.Items.AddRange(links.ToArray)
                Dim o, j As Long
                For o = 0 To ListBox1a.Items.Count - 1
                    For j = ListBox1a.Items.Count - 1 To (o + 1) Step -1
                        If ListBox1a.Items(o) = ListBox1a.Items(j) Then
                            ListBox1a.Items.Remove(ListBox1a.Items((j)))
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
                For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox1a.Items.Count - 1
                    Me.ListBox1a.Items(i) = Me.ListBox1a.Items(i).ToString.Replace("created by ", "")

                Next

                For Each s As String In ListBox1a.Items
                    Dim lvi As New NetSeal.NSListView
                    lvi.Text = s
                    NsListView1.Items.Add(lvi.Text)

                Next
```

It runs but I can't get the 'created by XXX' text.
I've tried many ways but got no luck, an hand would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are looking wrong string in the `attribute.Value`. What I see is that `attribute.Value.StartsWith("created by ")` must be changed to this one `attribute.Value.StartsWith("thread-plate__summary")`.

And to grab inner content of node you have to do this: `Select node.InnerText`;

```
' the example url to scrape
Dim url As String = "http://services.runescape.com/m=forum/forums.ws?39,40,goto," & Label6.Text
Dim source As String = GetSource(url)

If source IsNot Nothing Then
    ' create a new html document and load the pages source
    Dim htmlDocument As New HtmlDocument
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(source)

    ' Create a new collection of all href tags
    Dim nodes As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class]")

    ' Using LINQ get all href values that start with http://
    ' of course there are others such as www.
    Dim links =
        (
            From node
            In nodes
            Let attribute = node.Attributes("class")
            Where attribute.Value.StartsWith("thread-plate__summary")
            Select node.InnerText
        )

    Me.ListBox1a.Items.AddRange(links.ToArray)
    Dim o, j As Long
    For o = 0 To ListBox1a.Items.Count - 1
        For j = ListBox1a.Items.Count - 1 To (o + 1) Step -1
            If ListBox1a.Items(o) = ListBox1a.Items(j) Then
                ListBox1a.Items.Remove(ListBox1a.Items((j)))
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox1a.Items.Count - 1
        Me.ListBox1a.Items(i) = Me.ListBox1a.Items(i).ToString.Replace("created by ", "")

    Next

    For Each s As String In ListBox1a.Items
        Dim lvi As New NetSeal.NSListView
        lvi.Text = s
        NsListView1.Items.Add(lvi.Text)

    Next
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank Andy but didn't worked. The output was thread-plate__summary instead of the text I wanted to.

Comment: It worked Andy, thank you very much for your fast and effective answer!

Comment: The **Select attribute.Value & ":" & attribute.Value** in the top of the **Select node.InnerText** it's getting an error.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this? Moreover `Select Case` is used in wrong way. Here you can read more about of how to use case technique in linq: https://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/case-statement-equivalent-in-linq/

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this https://i.imgur.com/nx1IIvk.png   but whenever I put the Select node.InnerText it gives me an error. As you can see, without Select node.InnerText it's working just fine. Without Select Case https://i.imgur.com/o7gaK61.png

Comment: Because you cannot have two `select` statements.

Comment: You should use this: `Select new {node.InnerText, Select attribute.Value & ":" & attribute.Value}`

Comment: It doesnt work Andy... Type or 'With' expected. } Expected